# Lengthy subscript and commas formatting nicely

Tags: math-mode, formatting, subscripts

[image]How do I rewrite this equation nicely in LaTeX?

```
$d \leftarrow \min\{ \min_{\omega \in \Omega} {u^\omega_{c',i^\omega_{c',t'}}}, r_{c',t'}\}.$
```

There are at least two problems I see:

1. The two layered subscript with the `'` goes too far "down" in the first term and
2. There is a space between the `c'` and the comma under `r`, ideally the comma should be right below the `'`

Comment: Is so difficult to provide complete small document with your equation instead of equation fragment? Please extend it to MWE.

Comment: @Zarko added image.

Comment: image is in this simple case not needed, we need complete MWE (Minimal Working Example`, a small complete document beginning with `\begin{document}` and end with `\end{document}`. Why we should do write this from scratch, if you already have it?  Now you already already have answer with MWE , so my coment please consider in your future question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose one of these this hacks with `\smash` and some negative `\mkern` or `\mathrlap` (defined by `mathtools`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

 \begin{document}

$d \leftarrow \min\bigl\{ \min_{\omega \in \Omega} {u^\omega_{c'\mkern-5mu,i_{\smash{c'\mkern-5mu,t'}}^{^{\omega}}}}, r_{c'\mkern-5mu,t'}\bigr\}.$

$d \leftarrow \min\bigl\{ \min_{\omega \in \Omega} {u^\omega_{c\mathrlap{'},i_{\smash{c\mathrlap{'},t'}}^{^{\omega}}}}, r_{c'\mkern-5mu,t'}\bigr\}.$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there a more general way than the mkern? Also I am getting the same display with and without smash....

Comment: What do you mean exactly with ‘more general’? More  automatic? As to \smash, I used it because without it, the exponent (ω) was slightly raised.

Comment: Meaning without the -5mu, where the number is decided automatically.

Comment: I've posted a more  ‘automatic’ solution, using `\mathrlap`. This being said, the kerning won't change; since it will always be used for a prime symbol, and I think the first solution is slighly better. B.t.w., I had forgotten one negative kerning (corrected).

Comment: I've marked it as correct. But why do you think the first solution is better? Both solutions look the same to me visually.

Comment: In the second solution, the comma starts almost where the prime starts (0.3pt on the right). In the first solution, they're mre xentred w;.r.t. each other,the comma starts 0.7 on the right. But maybe I'm  nit-picking…